# have which-function-mode show @media query in css-mode?

Tags: css, which-function-mode

I'd like to know which @media query I'm in (those blocks are several pages long, so can't see them in a screenful), without going `2 C-M-u C-u C-SPC`  etc. each time I want to check. There is `which-function-mode`, but it only shows the selector, not the surrounding @media query. Anyone got a trick for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're feeling adventurous, you can try with CSS mode from the current master branch. `which-function-mode` should show the surrounding media query after [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=58d0642e1ca006fa550bff50fd328bc166c572da).